# SQL Update command performs an insertion instead of an update

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, sql-insert

I've been developing a database which one of its tables has the following design:

http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/843/3z08.jpg

I've tried to execute the following UPDATE command:

```
UPDATE TrainerPokemon SET PokemonID = 2, lvl = 55, 
AbilityID = 2, MoveSlot1 = 8, MoveSlot2 = 9, 
MoveSlot3 = 6, MoveSlot4 = 7 WHERE ID = 48
```

This was the data representation before the execution of the UPDATE command:

http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/853/01aa.jpg

And this was the data representation after the execution:

http://imageshack.us/scaled/landing/841/ul5j.jpg

As the image above shows, it is clear that the UPDATE command behaved like an INSERT command. Honestly, I've never seen this kind of behavior during all the years that I've worked with databases and SQL language.
What could ever have happened here?

Comment: This makes no sense, unless a `TRIGGER` fired. Can you reproduce it at will?

Comment: Check if there is any trigger defined on your table.

Comment: what happens if you run this query in SSMS?

Comment: In fact, there was a trigger which was implemented badly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are truly sending this statement, as it's shown, to the server then the only artifact that could change the behavior is a trigger.

Comment: Yes indeed! I forgot to tell that there was a trigger (with a bad implementation, by the way). Problem solved now, thanks!

Comment: @Mudkip, I'm glad I could be of assistance. Please consider marking it as the answer if it did in fact solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Unless it's a `TRIGGER`, I'd wager some test environment is erroneously pointing to this database.

Answer (score 2):

Check if there are any triggers defined on your table otherwise what you are saying it really is impossible. execute the following statement to check any triggers on your table.

```
SELECT SO.NAME, SC.[text]
FROM sysobjects SO INNER JOIN  syscomments SC
ON SO.ID = SC.ID
WHERE SO.[type] = 'TR'
AND SC.[text] LIKE '%TrainerPokemon%'
```

Hopefully most likely it is a trigger, once you are sure it is a trigger causing issues, just disable it before your update and enable it after you have done update.

Something like this

**DISABLE TRIGGER**

```
DISABLE TRIGGER tr_Triggername ON TrainerPokemon;
```

**ENABLE TRIGGER**

```
ENABLE TRIGGER tr_Triggername ON TrainerPokemon;
```